# How can I reference a `this` property within a method of `this`?

Tags: javascript

I append a `services` property to `this`:

```
function Client(){
   this.services = {
      'propertyName' : {}
   };
```

and then append a method to `this`, in which I need to reference the `services` property of the instance of `client`:

```
function Client(){
   this.services = {
      'propertyName' : {}
   };
   this.someMethod = function () {
       if (this.services['propertyName']) {
           //do something
       }
   }
}

var clientName = new Client();
```

But `this.services - line 6` is undefined. How can I use a property assigned to `this` in a method assigned to `this`? It seems like it *should* be possible because by the time that method is called by the constructor, the `services` property will exist for the object. Is this a language limitation? Is it possible? Should it be?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder What do you mean? It's a function that uses `this` is invoked with `new` -  a prototype to create instances of `Client` - how is it not a prototype?

Comment: It's not a prototype because it's not a prototype. It's just an object with a property on it. For it to be a *prototype* property, it would have to be on a different object that was the prototype of the object you're trying to use it on. For instance, if you moved `someMethod` *out* of the constructor and did `Client.prototype.someMethod = function() { /* ... */ };`, *that* would be a prototype property (`someMethod`) trying to access a non-prototype property (`services`). (There are also a couple of other ways.)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Ah, I *think of it* as a prototype for another object, but it's actually called a *constructor* right?

Comment: `Client` is a constructor function, yes. `this` within it (when it's called via `new`) is just referring to an object. (Sometimes called an *instance* of `Client`, but that's really class-based OOP terminology. Doesn't mean it's not helpful sometimes. :-) )

Comment: Please show us how you call that method. Sounds like a possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/20279484/1048572 to me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But this.services - line 6 is undefined.

That will depend entirely on *how you call* `someMethod`. If you call it like this:

```
clientName.someMethod();
```

...it'll be fine, because `this` within the call will be the object created by `new Client` that you've put the `services` property on. But in JavaScript, `this` is not a fixed thing with normal functions, it's set by *how you call* the function. So:

```
var f = clientName.someMethod;
f();
```

...would fail, because `this` wouldn't be the object you expect. (This isn't true of ES6's new "arrow" functions, which get `this` from where they're defined, not how they're called.)

You mostly see this when functions are used as callbacks:

```
doSomething(clientName.someMethod);
```

...because `doSomething` doesn't know what object to use as `this`.

You can fix it by using `Function#bind`:

```
doSomething(clientName.someMethod.bind(clientName));
```

or similarly:

```
var f = clientName.someMethod.bind(clientName);
f();
```

`Function#bind` creates a new function that, when called, will call the original with `this` set to the argument you give it.

---

Just to flesh out my ES6 comment above: In ES6, if you had:

```
function Client(){
   this.services = {
      'propertyName' : {}
   };
   this.someMethod = () => {                  // <== ES6 "arrow" function
       if (this.services['propertyName']) {
           //do something
       }
   }
}
```

...it wouldn't matter how you called `someMethod`, `this` would be what it is where that function was *created*. V. handy. :-)

Comment: While speaking in ES6, I can assure you, you are *not* [this guy](http://dilbert.com/strip/2010-12-23). Thanks for your help!